# How can I consecutively implement contradicting css classes in one javascript function to create a fade in/fade out effect on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a web page to only have one element showing at a time when the element is completely in the window. When the element is not in the window, I want to fade out, and when it comes fully into view, I want it to fade in.

As a beginner, the only thing I could think of when doing this was removing the previous class completely and adding the opposite, but no matter how I've tried to accomplish this (mostly just moving around my elements[i].style.animation = 'none' or null and changing the syntax of if statements.)

My javascript (in HTML file):

```
<script>
window.onscroll=function(){fade()};
    function fade(){
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block1,.block2');
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].offsetTop>window.pageYOffset && elements[i].offsetTop+elements[i].clientHeight<window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight){
          elements[i].style.animation='none';
          elements[i].style.animation=null;
          elements[i].className+=" pageFade";
          elements[i].style.opacity="1";
        }
        else{
          elements[i].style.animation='none';
          elements[i].style.animation=null;
          elements[i].className+=" outFade";
          elements[i].style.opacity="0";
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

My CSS

```
.pageFade{
  animation:reveal 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
  -webkit-animation-name:reveal 1.5s ease-out 1;
}

@keyframes reveal{
  0%{opacity:0}
  100%{opacity:1}
}

.outFade{
  animation:unreveal 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
  -webkit-animation-name:unreveal 1.5s ease-out 1;
}

@keyframes unreveal{
  0%{opacity:1}
  100%{opacity:0}
}
```

(-webkit- excluded)

Only my opacity commands are in action, my "fade" animations are not working... Any advice on what I should try?

Comment: Mixing style attributes and CSS classes is only going to confuse things. Do it all by assigning a single CSS class in your JS code. And set the end state of the animation in that class's CSS properties. While running the annimation overrides the assigned CSS class's properties.

Comment: You might want to consider using the `InterSectionObserver` API to check if elements are in view or not. I personally find it much easier to work with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Hello Kat, maybe you can improve your title with "show or fade element if it is completly in viewport" or something like that. It will help to understand the main requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use the script to add/remove a class.
2. Then, inside the class put the styles you want.

```html
<div class="block">BLOCK 1</div>
<div class="block">BLOCK 2</div>

<style>
 .block {
  width: 90px; height: 150px; background: red; margin: 6px;
  transition: opacity .9s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 .fade { opacity: 0; }
</style>

<script>
    function handleFade(){
  // use const in a var that is never reasigned
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
  // using forEach is clearer and more declarative
  elements.forEach(element => {
   // add a more expressive name to the conditions
   const condition1 = element.offsetTop > window.pageYOffset;
   const condition2 = element.offsetTop + element.clientHeight <
      window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
   // clean your if condition
   if(condition1 && condition2) element.classList.remove('fade');
   else element.classList.add('fade');
  });
    }

  // execute handleFade at the beginning in case user does not scroll.
    handleFade();

 // remove redundant anonymous function
    window.onscroll = handleFade;
</script>
```

In addition, I recommend this post in order to know [how-to-check-if-any-part-of-an-element-is-out-of-the-viewport-with-vanilla-js](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-check-if-any-part-of-an-element-is-out-of-the-viewport-with-vanilla-js/).

Hope it helps.